# How to validate one field or the other - two text inputs?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, jquery-validate

Using jQuery Validate to do it's job of validating a form. Problem is I need to get at least one phone number recorded in the form - either a PDf or url

Is there any inbuilt way of setting up the rules to do this and set message for this one also?

THis is my code:

```
$('#myform').validate({
          rules: {
              news_pdf: {
                      required: function(element) {
                            return $('#url_upload').val() == '';
                      }
                }
                news_url: {
                      required: function(element) {
                            return $('#file_upload').val() == '';
                      }
                },

          },

    });
```

Comment: Do you want to automate it? Or are you saying that your code doesn't work?

Comment: This code is working but how to set a message for this...when a person is attempting to enter second input field after entering the first one